# Haskell recursive function to read input from user until a condition, and then return the input as list

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, io

I'm making a function `readUntil` that reads lines from user. Reading stops when `f` returns True for a line. Then the lines are returned as a list (the line that returned True is not included in that list). Here's what I have at the moment (some really raw/pseudo code now, excuse me):

```
readUntil :: (String -> Bool) -> IO [String]
readUntil f = fmap reverse (go []) where
    go xs = do
    x <- getLine
    if f = True then return xs
                else go (x : xs)
```

I would also like to make `readUntil` recursive (or implement a recursive helper function).

Comment: `f = True`. I'm a bit surprised to see such check.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I did a bit of a pseudo code to start with (since I'm kinda stuck), as in "check if f is True here". Sorry I should've explained it.

Comment: Well I have the idea that you are quite close to a valid solution. Here you want that `f` applied with parameter `x` is `True`, so I guess with a few hints you can come up with a solution.

Comment: I changed it to `if f x == True` and it works, thank you!

Comment: `a == True` has the same value as `a`

Comment: Using `Control.Monad.Loops`: `unfoldWhileM (not . f) getLine`

Answer (score 1):

I've included a small example below.  You're pretty much at the solution.  The important bit is just remembering how you'd generate a non-monad recusive list, then just putting that in the monad.

```
collectUntil :: (Monad m) => m a -> (a -> Bool) -> m [a]
collectUntil act f = do
  x <- act
  if f x
    then return []
    else (x:) <$> collectUntil act f

readUntil :: (String -> Bool) -> IO [String]
readUntil = collectUntil getLine
```